# Loading errors for running rspec

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2

Am trying to run Rails 3.0 and Ruby 1.9.2 and am running Rspec 2.6.0 which I just downloaded. When I try to run Rspec, I get the following error message:

```
 Paul-Denlingers-MacBook-Pro:spec pdenlinger$ rspec spec
 No DRb server is running. Running in local process instead ...
 /Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/rspec-core-     2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:419:in `load':    
 no such file to load --       /Users/pdenlinger/rails3inaction/things_i_bought/bacon/spec/spec (LoadError)
from /Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/rspec-core-   2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:419:in 
`block in load_spec_files'
from /Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:419:
 in `map'
from /Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:419:
 in `load_spec_files'
from /Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:18:
 in `run'
from /Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:
 in `run_in_process'
from /Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:66:
 in `rescue in run'
from /Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:62:
 in `run'
from /Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:11:
  in `block in autorun'
```

Sorry for the code formatting problems; some of the lines just won't adjust.

What do I need to do to fix this problem?

Comment: are you running spork? read this to help you out with the config:http://blog.mattheworiordan.com/post/4701529828/full-stack-integration-testing-with-rails-3-cucumber

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your are telling `rspec` to search for the `spec` directory and then get all the specs there. If you are already in the `spec` directory, it will fail, so you have to run `rspec .` or get into the root directory for your app and run `rspec spec` from there.

Answer (score 1):

Paul-Denlingers-MacBook-Pro:spec pdenlinger$ bundle exec rspec

Comment: While your answer may solve the question, it is always better if you can provide a description of what the issue was and how your answer solves it. This is a suggestion for further improving this and future answers.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @NKN What link? The answer not provide a description however it's not a only link answer question.